# Why does a recursive lazy list blow the stack in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, linked-list, lazy-evaluation

I saw this snippet of Haskell in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44682/56183) by [proud haskeller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20370) on Meta PPCG:

```
x=2:x
```

I thought, "wait, I can do that in Scala!" So I tried:

```scala
lazy val x: List[Int] = 2 :: x
```

It compiled, and my console printed a nice `x: List[Int] = <lazy>`. But each of these lines results in a `StackOverflowException`:

```
x take 1
x.head
x(1)
x
```

Based on the last one, it looks like any attempt to use `x` blows the stack trying to compute `x` (either that or a stack overflow happens trying to print it in the console). How is Scala's laziness different from Haskell's laziness in this example? Is this a feature of Scala's `lazy val` or does the `List` class simply require a complete tail?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is `def x: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: x`. This produces an `immutable.Stream[Int]`.

A lazy variable is evaluated only if needed, but it is fully evaluated. A `Stream`, on the other hand, is a collection of lazy values. Each element is evaluated only when needed, but the entire collection might never be evaluated, which is why it can be infinite.

Comment: Not quite, you need the return type for it to compile, but still nice. With lazy vals it's `lazy val x: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: x`.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon, right you are. Busy composing the 2nd paragraph and missed that. I would argue, however, that there is little point in making the `Stream` val lazy. If it's a `val` then the results (evaluated elements) are memoized. If it's a `var` they aren't. Making it a `lazy val` doesn't buy you much.

Comment: Oops. Another typo trying to clarify the difference between `val` stream, which is memoized, and `def` (not `var`) stream, which is not memoized.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like I figured it out while formulating the question. It seems to be more a problem with `List` than with `lazy val`. To try this out, I made a simple `LazyList` implementation:

```
class LazyList(h: Int, t: => LazyList) {
  val head = h
  lazy val tail = t
}
```

Then I can do:

```
lazy val x: LazyList = new LazyList(1, x)
x.head // 1
x.tail.tail.tail.head // 1
```

So, Scala's laziness is really lazy after all, if you make everything lazy, at least.

Comment: Note that the exact same thing would have happened if you used a strict list in Haskell.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Interesting. I know very little Haskell, but I'm surprised it has a strict list type.